# Is there a way to use MSTest to run all tests for a set of parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mstest

I just have one parameter that can take two values. I would like to see two sets of my tests in the test runner, one for the first value, one for the second. How can I do this?

Comment: You should look into Pex http://weblogs.asp.net/robertxue/archive/2008/11/10/using-the-pex-to-write-unit-test-automatically.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use the [DataSource] attribute too:

http://callumhibbert.blogspot.com/2009/07/data-driven-tests-with-mstest.html

http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/01/18/How-to-simulate-RowTest-with-MS-Test.aspx

Comment: Data driven tests can be useful but for a parameter that can take only two values?

Comment: If I can use CSV files for the inputs, it shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

MSTest is very limited, but it never really troubled me. You can do parameterized tests like this:

```
[TestMethod] public void SomeMethod_WithValidArgs1_Succeeds()
{
    Assert_ThatSomeMethodSucceeds(0, "bla");
}

[TestMethod] public void SomeMethod_WithValidArgs2_Succeeds()
{
    Assert_ThatSomeMethodSucceeds(1, "bla");
}

[TestMethod] public void SomeMethod_WithValidArgs3_Succeeds()
{
    Assert_ThatSomeMethodSucceeds(1, "funcy");
}

private static void Assert_ThatSomeMethodSucceeds(
    int param1, string param2)
{
    // Act
    SubSystem.SomeMethod(param1, param2);
}
```